# get all id and value of input text in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony

I use twig and jquery and I need to get all the id and value of input text.

the code of my twig is given as follow

```
 <div id="formtest">
            {% for id, value in labels %}

           <p><input type="text"  name="" id="{{ id }}" placeholder="{{ value }}" />

            {% endfor %}
                </div>
```

and in my javascript:

```
jQuery('#formulaire').ajaxForm({

        beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) {

            var ids = [];
            var values=[];
            $("#formtest input").each(function() {
               ids.push($(this).attr("id") );
                values.push($(this).val());
                               });
             //$("#form_hide").val(ids);
            arr.push({name:'idtext', value:(ids)})
            arr.push({name:'valuestext', value:(values)});
        },

        success: function (data) {
                     jQuery('#main-content').html("done);

        },
        error: function () {
            jQuery('#main-content').html("error");

        }
    });
```

and in my controller:

```
 $values= $this->get('request')->request->get('valuestext');
        var_dump($values);
```

but this does not work

any idea please !!!!!

Comment: What is exactly that does not work? What's the result of your "var_dump" and what is that you expect?

Comment: with var_dump I get null

Comment: Have you debuged info that was send to server? It seems that you are sending incorrect data in "value".

Comment: Your inputs have no value! Add your data in "value" attribute, not "placeholder".